# Need to give custom page template for each language in WPML

Tags: templates, page-template, plugin-wpml

I need to give each page a custom/different page template for every language page in WPML.

eg: Let i have a test page in English and french. Is there any way out so that in English i give sidebar template while same page in french don't have sidebar template.

Note: Solution should not be any core condition to be put in code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish different sidebar content per language with either the [plugin Widget Logic](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-logic/), or with the [Dynamic Widgets plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/dynamic-widgets/)

Alternatively you can make different sidebar templates per language and use a conditional on the language:

```
if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='en'){
get_sidebar('en');
}
if(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE=='fr'){
get_sidebar('fr');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, unless you create your own "Page Attributes" meta box, and remove the default one.

And since a post can only have one template assigned, you'll need to create your own function that checks the page templates assigned to the current post and select the one which matches to the selected language (use a different meta key), then do your own template_redirect.